How can I satisfy mypy when I have a potential callable that involves Self?
I have a dataclass that has a field that might be a constant or might be a function taking Self. There's a helper function that just does the right thing -- if the field contains a constant, it returns the constant. If the field contains a function, it calls the function using self:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Self, Callable

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    my_func_field: str | Callable[[Self], str]
    
    def my_field(self) -> str:
        if isinstance(self.my_func_field, str):
            return self.my_func_field
        else:
            return self.my_func_field(self)

mypy doesn't like this (playground):
main.py:12: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "MyClass"; expected "Self"  [arg-type]

However, if I simplify the situation so it's just a callable, I don't run into this problem:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Self, Callable

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    my_func_field: Callable[[Self], str]
    
    def my_field(self) -> str:
        return self.my_func_field(self)

This is surprising to me. I assumed that the else branch in the first example would type-check exactly the same as the second example, because in the else branch, my_func_field has been narrowed to Callable[[Self], str], which is exactly the same type as the second example.
What am I missing here? Is it possible to get mypy to accept something, or do I have to use an # ignore comment?

This part looks like a mypy bug - you can try reporting it at https://gihub.com/python/mypy/issues. However, I'd recommend avoiding Self in non-trivial cases (for example, it's ill-defined in attribute positions, see this playground - the snippet passes mypy and pyright cleanly, but fails at runtime; that's a specification issue and not a bug).

As a workaround, you can explicitly annotate self as self: Self. You'll have to disable the error code redundant-self if it's turned on in your configuration, though.

@STerliakov thanks, I'll try reporting it as a bug. Do you have any alternate recommendation (vs. using Self) in those non-trivial cases?

I prefer to design interfaces in a way that doesn't need "same class" annotations for methods and attributes. Actually methods suffer from the same problem, and it doesn't matter whether you use Self or an explicit TypeVar there - the only fully safe (not allowing forbidden calls by upcasting) position for Self (or a corresponding TypeVar) is method return type - it's guaranteed to be safe thanks to LSP. For methods and attributes it's better to either use the base class explicitly (probably not reasonable here) or to make those private - Self should be safe anywhere within the class

Here's at least one workaround using string types instead of Self.
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Self, Callable

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    my_func_field: str | Callable[["MyClass"], str]
    
    def my_field(self) -> str:
        if isinstance(self.my_func_field, str):
            return self.my_func_field
        else:
            return self.my_func_field(self)


get_instance is an instance method that returns the current instance (self). Using -> Self as the return type tells mypy that this method returns the current class type.
create is a class method that serves as a factory, creating and returning a new instance of MyClass. Since it’s a @classmethod, cls is passed instead of self, and -> Self allows mypy to infer that it returns an instance of the same class.
By using Self, mypy should now correctly infer the return types without errors.
from typing import Self

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value

    def get_instance(self) -> Self:
        """Instance method returning the current instance"""
        return self

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, value: int) -> Self:
        """Factory method that creates a new instance of MyClass"""
        return cls(value)


This doesn't address the question at all. You've written completely unrelated code that happens to use the same feature.

Yeah, this seems pretty unrelated to the question at hand. Could you maybe try editing this response to directly implement my_field?

This has the feel of something written by ai

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
